# Reinvesting the dividends of a dividend paying stock

Tags: portfolio, dividends, geometric-brownian

Suppose we have a dividend paying stock that has the following dynamics:
$$dS_t=S_t((\mu-q)dt+\sigma dW_t)$$
With a continuous dividend yield $q$. What is the portfolio $Y_t$ that results out of starting with one unit of the stock and continuously reinvesting the dividends in the stock? 
My intuition tells me that
$$dY_t=dS_t+qS_tdt=S_t(\mu dt+\sigma dW_t)$$
So, is this just the same as a regular nondividend paying stock?

Comment: Your intuition is correct.